# Devise - "forgot password" function - Username and Password not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to set up the "forgot password" function that comes with devise. I am using rails 5. It always gives me the error: "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted"(Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Users::PasswordsController#create though.

My code looks like this:

In development.rb I added:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port:3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port => 587,
 :authentication => :plain,
 :domain => 'gmail.com',
 :user_name => 'xyz@gmail.com',
 :password => 'abcde',
 }
```

Under config > initialisers > devise.rb I added:

```
config.mailer_sender = "xyz@gmail.com"
```

and under config > environment.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Am I missing anything or did I do something wrong?

Also another question: I need to link it to my personal account (i.e. replace the user_name and password with the details of a real email account), there is no default devise account the emails get sent from, right? I'm just wondering because like this everyone in my team would be able to see the password of the mail account we're using, right?

Any advice would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SMTPAuthenticationError` is an error at the SMTP authentication layer.

This means that whatever SMTP service you're trying to use is reporting back some kind of authentication issue.

I do not use Gmail as my SMP, but this error seems strange to me as it says `Username and Password not accepted`, which is different from incorrect.

Further research shows that Gmail no longer accepts less secure SMTP requests.

> Google now doesn't accept login from less secure apps. So you need to go to https://myaccount.google.com/security scroll to the bottom and turn ON "Allow less secure apps: ON". Now when you add the SMTP details to "Send as" google will accept them. You need to do this for the email ID you are adding in your Send as section.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. After following the link from the email and resetting the password, it shows this: The action 'password' could not be found for UsersController. Did you miss anything?

Comment: 1) You're controller is `Users::PasswordsController` not `UsersController`. 2) Action is `#create` not `#password`.

Have you been overriding?

Comment: No I haven't overwritten anything. In my route.rb it says: devise_for :users, controllers: {
               sessions: 'users/sessions',
               passwords: 'users/passwords',
               registrations: 'users/registrations'
             }

Comment: It's very difficult to say from here, but off a whim I would say that your form is incorrect, i.e. the form is sending you to the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's related with your gmail settings. If you see errors like `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` while using gmail for sending out emails, visit your gmail settings and enable less secure apps:

`"MyAccount" > "Sign-in & security" > "Connected apps & sites" > "Allow less secure apps"`

Answer (score 0):

Go to your google email account setting and change this settings. and try more than 1 times.

[image]